# Why do we have to localize $/ in the code?

Tags: perl

I have this code which reads a file and then prints each string separated by a space in the next line in another file output1.txt. What I am wondering is if i remove $/ , it takes only the first line of uart1.txt. What is local doing here and in the end file handle is returned in $data? Is there any way I can do this task?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

open STDOUT, ">", "output1.txt" or die "$0: open: $!";

use strict; 
use warnings;

my $data= do {
open my $fh , '<','D:\perl_learning\uart1.txt' or die $!;
 local $/;
<$fh>;
};

while($data =~ /(\S+)/g)
{
my $word=$1;
printf"%s\n",$word; 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$/` is the record separator which is used for reading bits of a file at a time in a `while` loop. By default it's 'new line'.

However it's bad form to change it globally, because it may break other bits of your program.

`local` avoids this problem, by scoping the change to the current scope (practically 'this set of `{}`'). By default - when you `local`ize in this way, it sets the value to `undef`. Which means you'll read the whole file in one go.

So what this means is - read everything in `$fh` into `$data` but don't mess with `$/` globally.

Comment: ok got it so $/ now becomes local to the file so it reads the file in one go just as by default it will read the line in one go...thanks a lot !!

Comment: No, it isn't local to the file. It is local to the block.

Comment: By block u mean {} is it ? and in {}  in the code its just opening the file in read mode so in this specific case it must be local to the file...please correct me if i am wrong!